# How does the counter party @InitiatedBy flow receive parameters?

Tags: corda

How does the counterparty flow (for example, the buyer in the TwoPartyTradeFlow) receive parameters? The documentation does not explain this very clear to me.

So far it seems to me that in the TwoPartyTradeFlow, the Seller is passed the other party flow session, although you can also initialize this yourself using `initiateFlow(party)`. In the other examples I have seen, the counterparty receives the initiator's flow session. However, in this code snippet, the buyer receives additional parameters such as notary, price, etc. How are these passed in?

```
open class Buyer(private val sellerSession: FlowSession,
                 private val notary: Party,
                 private val acceptablePrice: Amount<Currency>,
                 private val typeToBuy: Class<out OwnableState>,
                 private val anonymous: Boolean) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

This code has been taken from the first code snippet here. https://docs.corda.net/head/flow-state-machines.html

Answer (score 1):

The `TwoPartyTradeFlow.Seller` and `TwoPartyTradeFlow.Buyer` are inlined flows. The actual flows that call them are

Initiating `SellerFlow` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/samples/trader-demo/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/traderdemo/flow/SellerFlow.kt)

InitiatedBy `BuyerFlow` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/samples/trader-demo/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/traderdemo/flow/BuyerFlow.kt)

The `SellerFlow` will preemptively send some payload to the buyer where the `BuyerFlow` being a responder will receive them and then subflow the `TwoPartyTradeFlow.Buyer(...)` with the given params.

Helpful link on how inline flows work [here](https://docs.corda.net/api-flows.html?#inlined-subflows)